# What Would Be The Consequences of A Never-Dying Archenemy on a Hero?

Tags: magic

In various video games, the main antagonist, the final boss, is supposedly destroyed or killed and yet comes back in the next game. There are many notable examples: Link and Ganondorf, Mario and Bowzer, Samus Aran and Ripley, Mega Man and Sigma.....my point is, what would be the effect of a *seemingly immortal* archenemy? I'm looking for the mental impact of a nemesis that always comes back, *despite* the hero's *best* efforts in battle, and that always manages to become a major threat to them *and* society in general.

Comment: What are the consequences of wildfires breaking out every season on firefighter's mind? Diseases returning to kill people after once being successfully treated?

Comment: Exhaustion, depression, and/or rage?

Comment: This question is much too broad in my opinion. How an individual (the hero) or society reacts to such a predicament seems like it would depend on a huge variety of factors. Any answer would essentially be a psychology/sociology textbook. However, I think generally speaking such an antagonist would be treated more like a natural disaster than an individual. Especially after dozens of resurgences.

Comment: This seems a basic writing question more than a world-building question: A *really* immortal (100% undefeatable) hero or villain means no tension in the story, nothing for the audience to invest in. It's boring. The Quest of the Ring Bearer doesn't matter, because Sauron will rise again regardless of success or failure...so why bother? Get on the Grey Ships and flee to Valinor for a few generations. Then it's Somebody Else's Problem. That's why LOTR tells the story of the *final* defeat of Sauron instead of all those other (temporary) victories.

Comment: Yet we have plenty of people invested in Mario, Metroid, and Legend of Zelda. Please, explain that phenomenon....

Comment: Isn't this a standard trope? After X00 years, the Demon King has reawakened, and it's time for a new set of heroes to stop his plans anew!

Comment: Your question makes sense only if you are asking for *character* actions in a consistent world. if you are asking for real-world game-player "investment" in game franchises, that's way, way off-topic.

Comment: In short, your question is half-story-based -it depends on the very individual mindset of your villainous villain and its approach at villainous villainy, +the relationship with the hero-, and half-opinion-based since it's too broad and unclear on the details of your world. Example of two opposite yet equally valid results : there are several Batman universes with very recurring villains, in many Batman kept the oath to never kill, but in [Earth-51](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_to_Final_Crisis) he was... More "definitive" in his judgement .

Answer (score 5):

#### We have professionals who battle immortal enemies as their job

There are people in modern society who constantly have their enemies respawn.

These come in varying degrees of metaphor - fire fighters vs bushfire, paramedics vs fentanyl victims,  police vs drugs, or more literally: police officers who apprehend and charge someone only to see them paroled and then have to chase them again when they re-offend.

More to the point: Many police fight the "same enemy" over and over, just the faces vary each time - I've heard a typical police shift can see 20+ "domestic disturbance" callouts - in Australia we have one every [2 minutes](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2015-05-29/domestic-violence-data/6503734?nw=0). It's basically the same quest, multiple times per day, done ad nauseam.

Every quest is successfully completed and the day saved, but the next day the same quest needs completing again.

#### And how's that affect their emotional state?

- They're [not more likely to have depression than other jobs](https://bmjopen.bmj.com/content/3/1/e001720)...
- But are [the profession most likely to commit suicide](https://www.addictioncenter.com/news/2019/09/police-at-highest-risk-for-suicide-than-any-profession/).
- They have a [statistically higher likelyhood](https://kutv.com/news/local/40-of-police-officer-families-experience-domestic-violence-study-says) of being abusive to their family.
- They're [3 times more likely](https://www.psychologytoday.com/au/blog/sure-recovery/201803/police-and-addiction)  to have a drug or alcohol addiction.

I think its reasonable to assume that your hero's battle against an immortal enemy will be similar to emergency workers battle against "immortal enemies". I expect the toll on their mental health will be similar to that of police.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you!